# According to Heisenberg, is quantum theory merely a calculation procedure for predictions?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, heisenberg

Is quantum theory just a mathematical tool for correct predictions, according to Heisenberg's views?

What are his personal ontological commitments in relation to quantum theory (if he had any ontological commitments at all)?

Comment: Heisenberg, in his *The Representation of Nature in Contemporary Physics*, wrote *"In the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics, the objective reality has evaporated, and quantum mechanics does not represent particles, but rather, our knowledge, our observations, or our consciousness of particles."* So no ontological commitments and a strong anti-realist view that the mathematics of QM was simply a tool for calculation - but I'm no expert.

Comment: No, it is a guide to new metaphysics that QM forces upon us. "Shut up and calculate" does not even describe Bohr's views, and Heisenberg invokes Aristotelian ontological conceptions of "matter" as "potentia", energy as "fundamental substance" *and* "form", and their interplay with classically grounded mind and even Hegelian *Zeitgeist*. His views are detailed in his book [Physics and Philosophy](https://archive.org/details/physics-and-philosophy-the-revolution-in-modern-scirnce-werner-heisenberg-f.-s.-c.-northrop/mode/2up), see also [Pangle's commentary](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24636444).